# Duda sobre insertar una imagen en mvc5 con sql server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una duda conforme a insertar una imagen .

en mi tabla en sql server esta definido como atributo image

y en asp.net lo puse como atributo booleano de la siguiente manera:

`public byte [] Imagen { get; set; }`

y para insertar mi valor lo puse asi:

```
            com.CommandText ="insert into registrousuario(Nombre,appaterno,apmaterno,correo,usuario,clave,imagen)values('" + rg.nombre + "','" + rg.appaterno + "','" + rg.apmaterno + "','" + rg.correo + "','" + rg.usuario + "','" + rg.clave +"',"+Convert.ToBase64String(rg.Imagen)+ "')";
```

y al momento que inserto los valores me muestra el siguiente error: La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 válida porque contiene un carácter que no es Base 64, más de dos caracteres de relleno o un carácter no válido entre los caracteres de relleno.

como podria convertir mi valor de booleano para que se pueda insertar en la table de sql server ya que yo lo tengo asi ?
Convert.ToBase64String(rg.Imagen)

tengo esto en .cshtml:

Comment: sobra un ' en la consulta.. no?